# how to print class variable using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following code:

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

res = requests.get('URL')
type(res)

Data = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
type(Data)

match = Data.find('div', class_='price')
print(match)
```

It works. It returns the **div** and class in **HTML** format but doesn't give the value that I want. The URL it refers to has the following HTML:

```
<div class="price">
   "25.00"
  <span class>1</span>
</div>
```

when I hover over the div or the `"25.00"` in inspect mode, it displays `"25.00 == 0$"`

produces a pop-up that states:

> "use 0$ in the console to refer to this element".

So, how could I display the "25.00" on python?

apologies; I'm a new programmer, and have had very little previous experience with HTML.

Comment: the apostrophes were the only way I could get stack to print the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take use of an :

```
find('div', class_='price').contents[0].strip()
```

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<div class="price">
25.00
<span class>1</span>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

soup.find('div', class_='price').contents[0].strip()
```